# How to proceed with Twitter dropping support for the Twitter SDK?

Tags: ios, twitter, sdk, twitterkit

Since Twitter announced that they will be discontinuing support for the Twitter SDK for iOS, Android and Unity (https://blog.twitter.com/developer/en_us/topics/tools/2018/discontinuing-support-for-twitter-kit-sdk.html), I am unsure of the best way to proceed with my application. I am specifically interested in options for iOS.

I am currently only using a subset of the full capabilities, primarily:

- Authentication
- Fetching tweets
- Displaying tweets

For authentication, OAuthSwift looks to be a possible replacement.
https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

For fetching tweets from the API, Swifter is a library that I have been using and could continue to use.
https://github.com/mattdonnelly/Swifter

However, I'm currently using the TWTRTweetView class of the Twitter SDK and am not aware of any other options to replace this.

Twitter seem to be suggesting to use web views to display tweets in apps but this option doesn't lend well to my use cases. I'm looking for a native solution.

Can anyone suggest any other alternatives or approaches to take in light of these developments?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the blog :

> Documentation and source code for all three SDKs on GitHub will remain
>   available for consumption in an archived state.

Also,

> You can fork the Twitter Kit project and build it into your app, or
>   copy the parts you need into your app. Or you can use Twitter’s
>   standard API to power your own native displays and login
>   functionality.

Comment: Is there any library that provides similar functionalities?